# Present Simple vs Present Perfect

Tags: grammar

I watched a video on Youtube on the channel "CineFix"  and in that video I heard this phrase:

> "Copolla and Lucas are friends from way back."

The usage of Present Simple here is against everything I've heard about this tense
I would say:

> "Copolla and Lucas have been friends from way back."

However, is it possible to use Present Simple in this case, when we use a point or a length of time, like "We are friends for 20 years"?

Comment: 'We are friends for 20 years' / 'We are friends from 2002' are ungrammatical, unacceptable. 'We are friends from way back' is an extragrammatical idiom (ie it uses normally unacceptable grammar in a fixed phrase, a string that has become idiomatic, acceptable through repeated use).